# C++: argp and global variables across several files

Tags: c++, getopt, argp

[Argp](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp-Global-Variables.html#Argp-Global-Variables) exposes version and bug information with the global variables `const char * argp_program_version` and `const char * argp_program_bug_address`. However, if the source is split across several files it's not at all obvious how to set these variables. Setting them globally (in either `main.cpp` or `parser.cpp`, with definitions in `parser.h`) doesn't seem to work at all.

How should I set these variables such that argp knows about them?

Comment: Do you `#include <argp.h>` in parser.h?

Comment: I hadn't, but tried it there to no avail.